# Lennox G20 furnace

Tags: wiring, furnace

I was reading about using the T terminal for the C wire for internet thermostat. I have different wiring
Thermostat  Furnace
RC          R
W.          W
Y           Blank
Rh          T
G.          G
The ac works. Can I still use the T wire for C as I have extra wire.

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagram for your furnace and/or photos of the wiring at both the thermostat and furnace ends?

Comment: What Thermostat and what furnace do you have (Make/Model). Your Furnace should have a wire diagram internal of the outer panel